# The variance of a sample from a normal population

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

Please consider the problem and my solution below. I match the answer in the back of the book, but some how, my solution does not feel right to me. Did I
do it the right way?

Problem:
A normal population has a variance of $15$. If samples of size $5$ are drawn from this population, what
percentage can be expected to have variances (a) less then $10$?

Answer:

Let $S^2$ be the sample variance and $n$ be the sample size. The expression $nS^2 / \sigma^2$ will have a chi-square distribution with $4$ degrees of freedom.
\begin{align*}
\sigma^2 &= 15 \\
\frac{nS^2}{\sigma^2} &= \frac{5S^2}{15} = \frac{S^2}{3} \\
S^2 &= 10 \\
\frac{nS^2}{\sigma^2} &= 10 / 3 \\
\end{align*}
Using R we find:
pchisq(10/3, df=4)  = 0.496
Hence the answer is $0.496$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The result is approximately $0.5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the right idea, but a minor mistake. ***If the sample variance*** is $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2,$ then
$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=n-1).$ But
$\sum_{n=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2/\sigma^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n).$
I assume you are dealing with the sample variance $S^2$ and need
to use the first distributional relationship.

Sometimes a 'reality check' via simulation helps to understand
the theory. 
Here's what happens when we consider a million samples
of size $n = 5$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100, \sigma = \sqrt{15}).$
The vector `v < 10` is a logical vector of `TRUE`'s and `FALSE`'s.
Its mean is the proportion of its `TRUE`'s.
With a million iterations, one can expect about 2 or 3 decimal 
places of accuracy. The exact probability is $P(S^2 < 10) = 0.3849.$

```
set.seed(1776)
v = replicate( 10^6,  var(rnorm(5, 100, sqrt(15))) )
mean(v < 10)
[1] 0.385153               # aprx P(S^2 < 10)
2*sd(v < 10)/sqrt(10^6)
[1] 0.0009732634           # aprx 95% margin of simulation err
pchisq(8/3, 4)
[1] 0.38494                # exact P(S^2 < 10) from CHISQ dist'n
```

[image]

Comment: I was told that I was right and now I am told that I am wrong. I am not sure who to listen to.

Comment: What can I say: Start by making sure you understand what def'n of $S$ is used in your text. Does it assume the value of the sample mean $\mu$ is known--or estimated by $\bar X.$ By my def'n of $S^2,$ it is not true that $nS^2/\sigma^2 \sim$ CHISQ($n-1$).// If the answ. book is wrong, it wouldn't be the first time that ever happened. We get a lot of those on this site.  // I have checked my answ, but if it is wrong, it wouldn't be my 1st mistake. // You say, "[M]y solution does not feel right to me." Why don't you use what you know to be confident of your own answer--whatever you decide?

Comment: The book, as well as myself, is working with the knowledge that the sample mean is known.